# Foundation 5 - make background-image fill entire column

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, background-image

I'm trying to create the following effect with Zurb Foundation. Basically, two columns, each half the screen:

```
<div class="small-6 columns"><!-- MAKE IMAGE COVER HERE --></div>
<div class="small-6 columns">
   <h1>title</h1>
   <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

I'm trying to achieve the following visual effect:

[image]

The problems I'm facing:

- If I just is an `<img/>` tag, it doesn't have the "cover" effect -- either the width or height is not fully covered.
- if I set `background-image:` to the `<div class='small-6 columns'>`, the image doesn't show up.
- the left/right padding on columns doesn't allow the image to entirely cover the container. However I'm hesitant to remove them as I dont want to break the responsive functionality of columns.

**Current Code:**

*Markup*:

```
<div class="small-12 medium-6 columns thumb-bg"></div>
<div class="small-12 medium-6 columns>
  <h1>title</h1>
  <p>content</p>
</div>
```

*SCSS*:

```
  .thumb-bg {
    background-image: url('www.image-url.com');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #464646;
  }
```

Comment: Why not set full height on the `thumb-bg`: http://codeply.com/go/8SMXlNSbZp?

Comment: @Skelly : the problem with that is it distorts the aspect ratio of the image. I need a solution that scales the image to fit the container without ruining its aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image doesn't show up when you put it as a background because the element actually has no content. You must specify a width and height. If it isn't going to change you can use:

```
.thumb-bg{
    background: url('www.image-url.com') center center no-repeat;
    background:cover;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: The problem is the container is responsive, so I need something that will ill it with all sizes -- not sure if hard setting a pixel value is the right approach. Otherwise this works great.

Comment: Its hard to say without seeing the rest of your code and understanding your layout,  what I would do is start with a fixed size, and use media queries as the screen size shrinks to adjust for the smaller layouts. You could also try playing around with min-width and min-height.

Comment: Also, take a look at collapsing your rows to get rid of the padding in foundation: `<div class="row medium-collapse">`  - http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html

Answer (score 0):

Let's go over your problems:

> If I just is an  tag, it doesn't have the "cover" effect --
>   either the width or height is not fully covered.

I assume you mean you want to put something in front of this "cover"? If so, you can put content in front of it with position:absolute and z-index.

> if I set background-image: to the , the
>   image doesn't show up.

Given the css above, div.thumb-bg doesn't have dimensions. Add height and width.

> the left/right padding on columns doesn't allow the image to entirely
>   cover the container. However I'm hesitant to remove them as I dont
>   want to break the responsive functionality of columns.

You can selectively remove padding for these columns with a utility class and that won't prevent it from being responsive.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've added `height: 100%;` to `.thumb-bg`, and it gets the image to fill the entire container (how I want), however the problem is the aspect ratio is all distorted. I need the image to fill the container, but maintain aspect ratio (sides/bottoms can be clipped if necessary as long as image isn't distorted ratio).

Comment: background-size: cover shouldn't distort the image. Are you using the same markup above and the image is in the div?

Comment: the image is in a `background: url()` CSS property, not an image tag.

Comment: I should also note that this is inside a responsive container, so not a fixed height.